# Python switching the display based on input using If, Else

Tags: python

I want to display print text based on my Input value using IF/Else or Switch. And Also let me know how to use switch case for below code.

```
 # OnButtonOK after clicking it, display the input value    
  def OnButtonOK(self):
    Input = self.entrytext.get()
    # self.text.insert(END, Input + '\n')
    # self.scroll.config(Input = self.text.yview)
    print Input
    useroption = atoi(Input)
    # self.OnButtonClick();
    if (useroption == 1):
            print "input is output"
        self.SubMenu1();
    else:
        print "Error:Invalid"

    return;

def SubMenu1(self):
        print 'SubMenu1'
    return;

def SubMenu2(self):
        print 'SubMenu2'
    return;

def SubMenu3(self):
        print 'SubMenu3'
    return;
```

I am able to print only else part:

```
if (useroption == 1):
            print "input is output"
        self.SubMenu1();
    else:
        print "Error:Invalid"
```

Let me know where exactly i am going wrong.

Comment: You go to on wrong way ? Create all menu without any data cos how to resolve all `relationship` errors ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple beginner's mistake, you're indenting it worng:

```
if (useroption == 1):
        print "input is output"
    self.SubMenu1();
else:
    print "Error:Invalid"
```

should be

```
if (useroption == 1):
    print "input is output" # You had an indent too many here
    self.SubMenu1();
else:
    print "Error:Invalid"
```

Python is indentation sensitive; too many or too few indentations will break your code.

Comment: Tried same as you suggested showing unexpected indent. In my code it is not showing. If my implementation is right it should work right.

Comment: I ended up having the same error in my code, indentation messed up when I turned it into a code block, sorry, try it now. (the irony, on a monday morning)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have indentation problems in your code:
Python use 4 spaces(you can use 1 space but 4 is good practice) indentation language. Means if/else statement will be like this:

```
if a == 1:
    print("A = 1") # 4 spaces w.r.t to above statement
elif a == 2:
    print("A = 2")
elif a ==3:
    print("A = 4")
else:
    print("A = pta nahi")
```

you can use above if/else statements as a switch case and also your indentation problem will be solved